# Add the same index of a list if they are similar in another specific index

Tags: python

I'm programming in python and have a list of lists of

```
a=[[1234,32.5,'John',1114],[1234,16.3,'John',1115],[1235,25.3,'John',1116],
  [1239,16.3,'Lisa',1117]]
```

How can I merge the lists of the similar element in sub-index `[0]` and remove the list that contains the smallest element of index `[3]` ?

Expected output:

```
a=[[1234,48.8,'John',1115],[1235,25.3,'John',1116],[1239,16.3,'Lisa',1117]]
```

since

```
 a[1][3] > a[0][3] (1116 > 1115)
```

`a[0][1]` will be added to `a[1][1]` and `a[0]` will be completely removed.

I'm planning to use this to a list of ten thousands of lists.

EDIT:

I''ve made:

```
old=[[1234,32.5,'John',1114],[1234,16.3,'John',1115],[1235,25.3,'John',1116],[1239,16.3,'Lisa',1117]]

memory=old[0]

new=[]

for x, t in enumerate(old):
    if t==memory:
        new.append([t[0],memory[1]+t[1],t[2],t[3]])
        memory=t
```

But this would not work on lists if there are more than two lists that are similar in index [0], the code should be run again and again depending on how many similar elements are there. In application, my list of lists would have hundreds of similar elements in a specific index.

Comment: What have you attempted, and what in particular are you struggling with?

Comment: I already made a function that would do the function in two lists, but it's not efficient because I'm planning to use this to an enormous list of lists.

Comment: Really hard to tell which subindices are suppose to merge and which ones are supposed to sum. Which are unique ids?

Comment: Then I suggest you add your inefficient code, and detail why you believe it is inefficient. This would increase the likelihood of your question helping others, and of getting a suitable answer.

Comment: I''ve made:

old=[[1234,32.5,'John',1114],[1234,16.3,'John',1115],[1235,25.3,'John',1116],
  [1239,16.3,'Lisa',1117]]

memory=old[0]

new=[]

for x, t in enumerate(old):
     if t[0]==memory[0]:
          new.append([t[0],memory[1]+t[1],t[2],t[3]])
          memory=t

but this would not work on lists if there are more than two lists that are similar in index [0], the code should be run again and again depending on how many similar elements are there.

Comment: @MichaelEsporlas I appreciate your effort to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is to *group* your data by the common keys. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is made for this, and you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to group by the key elements of each sublist.

Once iterating over the groups, tracking the respective sum and maximum you need is not hard. This does assume that you intend on *keeping the maximum* and not removing the minimum, as having more than 2 elements in a group would make this impossible to do while summing the second elements.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def merge(data):
    out_data = []
    for _, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0, 2)):
        key_num, to_sum, key_name, to_max = next(group)
        for _, sum_val, _, max_val in group:
            to_sum += sum_val
            to_max = max(to_max, max_val)
        out_data.append([key_num, to_sum, key_name, to_max])
    return out_data
```

**Demo**

```
>>> a = [[1234,32.5,'John',1114],
         [1234,16.3,'John',1115], 
         [1235,25.3,'John',1116], 
         [1239,16.3,'Lisa',1117]]

>>> merge(a)
[[1234, 48.8, 'John', 1115],
 [1235, 25.3, 'John', 1116],
 [1239, 16.3, 'Lisa', 1117]]
```

---

It is also worth noting that if you have many operations to apply to tabular data like this, you may want to look into the [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Using Pandas, a succinct solution to your problem could be

```
import pandas as pd

def pd_merge(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)    
    return (df.groupby((0, 2), as_index=False)
              .agg({1: 'sum', 3: 'max'})
              .sort_index(1))
```

Comment: Thank you! I apologize if I did not explain it well. I will see into that pandas groupby function. I'm  working on dataframes with list of dictionaries and I will study this deeply. Gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution, it seems that can handle elements that more than 2:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a=[[1234,32.5,'John',1114], [1234,32.5,'John',1113],[1234,16.3,'John',1115],[1235,25.3,'John',1116],  [1239,16.3,'Lisa',1117]]

def merge_list(data):
    total_dic = defaultdict(list)
    new_data = []
    for elem in a:
        total_dic[elem[0]].append(elem)

    for dic_elem in total_dic:
        total_dic[dic_elem].sort(key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=False)
        if(len(total_dic[dic_elem]) > 1):
            new_data.append(total_dic[dic_elem][1:])
        else:
            new_data.append(total_dic[dic_elem][0])
    return new_data

print(merge_list(a))

[[[1234, 32.5, 'John', 1114], [1234, 16.3, 'John', 1115]], [1235, 25.3, 'John', 1116], [1239, 16.3, 'Lisa', 1117]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I've managed to answer my problem with the use of itertool's groupby

Here is my working prototype:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


def merge(data):
    out_data = []
    for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter('name','time')):
        id_temp = 0
        dep_temp=0

        dict_temp={}
        for t in group:
            dict_temp=t
            if t["deposit_id"] < id_temp:
                dict_temp['deposit_id']=id_temp
            else:
                id_temp=dict_temp['deposit_id']
            dep_temp+=dict_temp['deposit']
        dict_temp['deposit'], dict_temp['deposit_id'] = dep_temp, id_temp
        out_data.append(dict_temp)
    return out_data

a = [{'name':'John','time':1234,'deposit':16.7,'deposit_id':1115},
 {'name':'John','time':1234,'deposit':24.3,'deposit_id':1116},
 {'name':'John','time':1234,'deposit':65.3,'deposit_id':1117},
 {'name':'John','time':1235,'deposit':95.3,'deposit_id':1118},
 {'name':'Lisa','time':1235,'deposit':95.3,'deposit_id':1119}]

b=merge(a)

for t in b:
    print t
```

Output

```
{'deposit_id': 1117, 'deposit': 106.3, 'name': 'John', 'time': 1234}
{'deposit_id': 1118, 'deposit': 95.3, 'name': 'John', 'time': 1235}
{'deposit_id': 1119, 'deposit': 95.3, 'name': 'Lisa', 'time': 1235}
```